# Segmentation Fault due to vectors

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I have a program that is supposed to calculate the trajectory of a pendulum with the fourth order runge kutta method and the euler cromer method, unfortunately... I have a segfault.

I have no idea how to fix this, as you can see I have a few std::cout 's to attempt debugging, but they don't even output. This leads me to believe that the function never makes it to executing main();

My current intuition says that it errors out during the function declarations, but if I am wrong I would like to know. If at all possible, can you describe the techniques you used to debug?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>

#define N 1

// Pendulum Variables
double d_pendLength = 1.0, d_pendMass = 1.0; // Pendulum Properties
double d_viscParam = 1.0, d_gravity = 1.0; //9.80665; // Enviromental Factors
double d_dAmp = 0.0, d_dFreq = 0.0; // Driving Force

double d_initTheta = 0.0, d_initAVel = 0.0; //Initial Conditions

void v_rungekutta(double d_time, std::vector<double> d_pendulum, double d_step);
void v_eulercromer(double d_time, std::vector<double> d_pendulum, double d_step);
double d_derivative(double d_time, std::vector<double> d_pendulum, int i_de);

int main(void)
{
    // Numerical Variables
    double d_step = 0.01, d_mTime = -1, d_mPeriod  = 300;

    // Global Variables
    double d_time = 0.0, d_period = 0.0, d_limit;

    // Function Vectors
    std::vector<double> d_pendulum (2);

    // Settings
    std::string plot = "theta", algo = "rk4";


    std::cout << "START!";
    std::ofstream file_output;
    std::cout << "HAIDATA!";
    file_output.open("pendulum.data");

    std::cout << "HAI!";
    d_pendulum.at(0)= d_initTheta;  //Initial Theta
    d_pendulum.at(1)= d_initAVel;   //Initial Omega
    std::cout <<"BAI!";

    if (d_mPeriod > 0)
    {
        d_limit = d_mPeriod;
    }
    else if (d_mTime > 0)
    {
        d_limit = d_mTime;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "No Limit Specified";
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int i_currentStep=1; i_currentStep*d_step<=d_limit;i_currentStep++)       
    {
        d_time = i_currentStep*d_step;

        if (algo == "rk4")
        {
            v_rungekutta(d_time, d_pendulum, d_step);
        }
        else if (algo == "ec")
        {
            v_eulercromer(d_time, d_pendulum, d_step);
        }
        file_output << d_time << d_pendulum.at(0) << d_pendulum.at(1) << std::endl;
    }


    file_output.close();
    d_pendulum.clear();

    return 0;
}


void v_rungekutta(double d_time, std::vector<double> d_pendulum, double d_step)
{
    double h=d_step/2.0;  
    std::vector<double> t1, t2, t3, k1, k2, k3, k4;
    int i;

    for (i=N;i>0;i--) t1[i]=d_pendulum.at(i)+0.5*(k1[i]=d_step*d_derivative(d_time, d_pendulum, i));
    for (i=N;i>0;i--) t2[i]=d_pendulum.at(i)+0.5*(k2[i]=d_step*d_derivative(d_time+h, t1, i));
    for (i=N;i>0;i--) t3[i]=d_pendulum.at(i)+ (k3[i]=d_step*d_derivative(d_time+h, t2, i));
    for (i=N;i>0;i--) k4[i]=d_step*d_derivative(d_time+d_step, t3, i);

    for (i=N;i>0;i--) d_pendulum.at(i) += (k1[i]+2*k2[i]+2*k3[i]+k4[i])/6.0;
}

void v_eulercromer(double d_time, std::vector<double> d_pendulum, double d_step)
{
    int i;
    for (i=N;i>0;i--) d_pendulum.at(i) += d_derivative(d_time, d_pendulum, i)*d_step;
}

double d_derivative(double d_time, std::vector<double> d_pendulum, int i_de)
 {
    double dtheta = d_pendulum.at(1);
  if (i_de==0) return dtheta;
  double domega = d_pendulum.at(1)+((-d_gravity/d_pendLength)*sin(d_pendulum.at(0)))+(-d_viscParam*(d_pendulum.at(1)))+(d_dAmp*sin(d_dFreq*d_time));
  if (i_de==1) return domega; 
  if (i_de < 0) return 0; // 0 is a possible value, exit with exit func.
}
```

## SOLUTION

My problem was that I had not been properly accessing the vectors in rungekutta and I had not given them a starting size.

Before

```
    void v_rungekutta(double d_time, std::vector<double> d_pendulum, double d_step)
    {
        double h=d_step/2.0;  
        std::vector<double> t1, t2, t3, k1, k2, k3, k4;
        int i;

        for (i=N;i>0;i--) t1[i]=d_pendulum.at(i)+0.5*(k1[i]=d_step*d_derivative(d_time, d_pendulum, i));
        for (i=N;i>0;i--) t2[i]=d_pendulum.at(i)+0.5*(k2[i]=d_step*d_derivative(d_time+h, t1, i));
        for (i=N;i>0;i--) t3[i]=d_pendulum.at(i)+ (k3[i]=d_step*d_derivative(d_time+h, t2, i));
        for (i=N;i>0;i--) k4[i]=d_step*d_derivative(d_time+d_step, t3, i);

        for (i=N;i>0;i--) d_pendulum.at(i) += (k1[i]+2*k2[i]+2*k3[i]+k4[i])/6.0;
    }
```

After:

```
    void v_rungekutta(double d_time, std::vector<double> d_pendulum, double d_step)
    {
        double h=d_step/2.0;  
        std::vector<double> t1 (2), t2 (2), t3 (2), k1 (2), k2 (2), k3 (2), k4 (2);
        int i;

        for (i=N;i>0;i--) t1.at(i)=d_pendulum.at(i)+0.5*(k1.at(i)=d_step*d_derivative(d_time, d_pendulum, i));
        for (i=N;i>0;i--) t2.at(i)=d_pendulum.at(i)+0.5*(k2.at(i)=d_step*d_derivative(d_time+h, t1, i));
        for (i=N;i>0;i--) t3.at(i)=d_pendulum.at(i)+ (k3.at(i)=d_step*d_derivative(d_time+h, t2, i));
        for (i=N;i>0;i--) k4.at(i)=d_step*d_derivative(d_time+d_step, t3, i);

        for (i=N;i>0;i--) d_pendulum.at(i) += (k1[i]+2*k2[i]+2*k3[i]+k4[i])/6.0;
    }
```

Comment: Try with a debugger like gdb, lldb, or the one in Visual Studio. Time invested in learning them is well spent.

Comment: By the way, function declarations are not executed. The compiler will produce an executable that starts at the beginning of your `main()` function (possibly with some static initialization before-hand).

Comment: I'm running a Linux distro, so I used gdb. I found out that I wasen't using .at(i) on some arrays, and that I had not given some a size either. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I can see at first glance is that you are trying to access elements in empty vectors. Try to replace `[]` operators with `at()` method. The difference is that the former doesn't check bounds with a possibility of producing segfault, whereas the latter does, throwing an exception if index is out of bounds.

Comment: How would I catch such an exception?

Comment: without a response to @NictraSavios's question, this is but half an answer.

Comment: This usually causes a big slowdown. Most algorithms, this one included, do many array accesses. Checking the vector size once, up front, is an order of magnitude faster.

Answer (score -1):

I saw the solution above which answered 9 years ago. btw i just answering with simple example, it may help full to the beginners. whoever can't understand big solution or how to implement.

actually in C++ vector we should use methods whatever available in vector class.

For example:
square brackets  [ ]: we cannot use this to check the boundary of the vector array. it can just return value if it has, else throw segmentation error or something else.

instead of "[ ]" (square brackets) we can use "at()" (method) it can check the boundary of the vector array. if it has value return, else it will handle the error properly.

```
vector<int> nums;
nums.push_back(1);
nums.push_back(5);
nums.push_back(7);
nums.at(0) // 1
nums.at(6);// out of bound
nums[6] // segmentation fault
```

Comment: This is the same advice as the answer from 9 years ago. Still bad, though.